# dotConnect for Oracle Hebrew problem - gibberish - getting ¿¿¿¿

Tags: oracle, dotconnect

I'm trying to create EF through Devart dotConnect with an Oracle database that includes Hebrew chars.

In regedit:

```
NLS_LANG = HEBREW_ISRAEL.IW8ISO8859P8
```

In web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <globalization requestEncoding="windows-1255"
      responseEncoding="windows-1255" fileEncoding="windows-1255"
      culture="he-IL" uiCulture="he-IL" />
</system.web>
```

In Master:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I'm getting "  ¿¿¿¿" instead of real values. You can I fix it?

Comment: so you've got three different encodings in three different places. what happens when you put roughly the same one everywhere?

Comment: What is the database and national character set of the database?  Are you storing the data in a `VARCHAR2` column?  Or `NVARCHAR2`?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to edit in regedit the language tag

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Unicode connection string parameter to true.
To achieve this just add the "Unicode=true;" to the Oracle connection string in the application configuration file.